# How can I get the series of an indicator using IMF API?

Tags: node.js, rest

The IMF docs does not tell how we can achieve that. It only says "GetMaxSeriesInResult method returns the maximum number of time series that can be returned by CompactData.
In order to obtain the data use the following request:

```
http://dataservices.imf.org/REST/SDMX_JSON.svc/GetMaxSeriesInResult
```

and CompactData is this, basically:

```
http://dataservices.imf.org/REST/SDMX_JSON.svc/CompactData/{database ID}/{frequency}.{item1 from
dimension1}+{item2 from dimension1}+{item N from dimension1}.{item1 from
dimension2}+{item2 from dimension2}+{item M from dimension2}?startPeriod={start
date}&endPeriod={end date}
```

Somehow, we have to merge GetMaxSeriesInResults with CompactData service

I tried to attach the indicator id as a query param like this, between other things, does not work.

```
http://dataservices.imf.org/REST/SDMX_JSON.svc/GetMaxSeriesInResult?REER.PC
```